# To compare a text in a database with the text of a form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, sql

I currently have a text field in my form. This text field is part of a mysql database. Now I would like to compare the text of the database with the new text that the user just posted and if in this text there are 50% or more words and commum then I consider it as spam and I cancel The form.

The problem is that I do not know how to compare the text in the database with the new text sent.

Any ideas ? Thank you for your help

Comment: You need [FULL TEXT SEARCH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) to compare the similarities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write for individual words from $_POST

```
$arr = explode(' ',trim($_POST[data])); //if data="Hi There I go"

if (strpos($mysqltext, $arr[0]) !== false) { //$arr[0]="Hi"
    echo 'true';
}
```

To end of array.

Comment: Yes thank you this solution is already implemented. My problem is just at the level of the comparison with respect to the percentage of words in commums

Comment: Thank you Aung :)